# How do i set class variables to display in my jsp using an interceptor?

Tags: java, struts2, interceptor, interceptorstack

I'm trying to create an interceptor in struts which sets a couple of class variables (which i would like to use in a header page).  This is what I have done

struts.xml

```
 <interceptors>
        <interceptor class="com.googlecode.sslplugin.interceptors.SSLInterceptor" name="secure" />
        <interceptor class="org.my.action.HeaderInterceptor" name="headerInterceptor" />
        <interceptor-stack name="myStack">
            <!-- TODO : uncomment this before release
            <interceptor-ref name="secure">
                <param name="useAnnotations">true</param>
                <param name="httpsPort">443</param>
                <param name="httpPort">80</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            -->
            <interceptor-ref name="headerInterceptor" />
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
<default-interceptor-ref name="myStack"/>
```

the interceptor code

```
public class HeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//added for inputs to HEADER
private String investorName;
private String investorImage;


@Override
public void destroy() {}

@Override
public void init() {}

@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
    setHeaderAttributes();
    return actionInvocation.invoke();
}


private void setHeaderAttributes()
{
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    Object invObj = session.getAttribute(RangDeServerUtils.USER);
    if( null != invObj && invObj instanceof Investor){
    Investor investor = (Investor) invObj;
        this.investorName = investor.getFirstName();
        this.investorImage = Integer.toString(investor.getImageId());
    }
}

//have removed getters and setters for the class variables

}
```

On every request the interceptor is being hit and the class variables are set but they are not displaying on the jsp.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?? Pls help.

Comment: I've never tried to access static members.  Can you show your JSP to illustrate how you are trying to access them?  Also, you should just hard wire some values into those members when trying to troubleshoot this; or perhaps debug and verify that the code that initializes those things is running. There are several obvious pieces to verify . . .

Comment: I dont think you can access the getters of an interceptor from a jsp. I would suggest specifying getters and setters in your action class and have struts inject them, this can be done via an action mapping that uses ognl expressions.

Comment: Also since you are storing investor object in session, why dont you just store name and image there also, and then access the session variable from your jsp

Comment: I don't understand; interceptors aren't on the value stack. Also, interceptors are instantiated only once per configuration, so this wouldn't work anyway- like servlet, using instance variables like this will break very quickly. You could set them on an action, but the object is *already* in session, so I don't see the point.

Comment: Also, your interceptor is NOT thread-safe (due to investorImage and investorName variables). What do you *really* need ?

Comment: Post the JSP and action configuration.

Comment: @DaveNewton - The object in the session can be an instance of 5 other object types. Therefore I didn't want to the instanceof check in the jsp (i don't think it is included in the default and struts and jstl tag libraries. I have used it somewhere else using an additional tag function that i had implemented). Pls correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Karthik I'd argue you're working around a design issue more than anything else.

Comment: @DaveNewton so are you suggesting that its better that i put this logic in the jsp instead of using an interceptor? By the way i set the variables as part of the request and it worked.. [have posted my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14416247/1990904)

Comment: No, I'm suggesting if you have to use instance of there's probably a missing interface or something.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question, as written, but there seems to be a debate as to whether or not this is what you really want/need/should do. Whatever the case here is how you use an interceptor to set values on your Actions class.

[See the source of the parameters interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ParametersInterceptor.html)

I would recommend downloading the source for your current version, just to see how it works.

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation){
   //get the current action
   Object action = invocation.getAction();
   //figure out if your action supports what you want to do, either check its
   // interface or use reflection (or apache Bean/Property Utils) to see if it 
   // supports the properties you are interested in...
   if(action typeof MyInterface){
       MyInterface mi = (MyInterface)action;
       //set what you need how you need it
   }


   return invocation.invoke();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing

```
    this.investorName = investor.getFirstName();
    this.investorImage = Integer.toString(investor.getImageId());
```

in ther interceptor, I did

```
request.setParameter("investorName", investor.getFirstName());
request.setParamter("investorImage", Integer.toString(investor.getImageId()));
```

and it worked.